# How to access ios 6 mobile safari web inspector on Windows or Linux?

Tags: mobile-safari, ios6, web-inspector

Is it possible to access the new ios 6 mobile safari Web Inspector from a Windows or Linux platform ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that's not possible.
This feature is just available in "Safari v6" that could debug iOS 6's Safari, and "Safari v6" is only available on OS X Lion and higher (at least for now!), so it is not possible on Windows or Linux at the time of this answer.